# What are the correct Conditions to test for Weighted Die?

Tags: r

I was commanded with the following question. Write a function, named pdice, to simulate a weighted die that has probability of landing on 1:6 of (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6) respectively.  You can simulate this by using the parameter prob = p in the sample function, where p is a vector of non-negative numbers of length 6 (at least one needs to be >0). It will use p/sum(p) as the probabilities. This function has arguments p, n. Check ?sample to find out what conditions you need to check for p. Your function should generate an error message if these conditions are not met. Below is my code thus far, which runs, though giving back a warning about a coercing error of double to logical.

```
pdice <- function(n, p){
    weightofDies <- c(1/40, rep(4/40,4), 23/40)
    roll <- sample(1:6, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = weightofDies)
        if(n>0 && all(p=1)) {
           return(roll)
        }
        else {
           print("Error, Conditions Not Met")
        }

     }
```

I'm confused when the question says use parameter prob = p, then defines p as a vector of non-negative numbers of length 6. How can a probability be defined as a vector? Thus when it came to the conditions my brief understanding made sure the number of rolls (n) was greater than zero. And with p I just went on ahead to make sure the probabilities of this "Vector" added up to one. However not sure if my process thus far is correct. I created my biased probabilities via weightofDies.

Comment: This is a homework question. I will give you a bit of feedback without a straight p solution (although there is no rule against it on SO). Your `weightOfDies` should be equal to `p / sum(p)` as stated in your question. And then you should perform a test that `sum(weightOfDies) == 1` and `n > 0` prior to calling `sample`. Think of it logically. "1) Find my probabilities, 2) test that I can actually take a sample, 3) take a sample or return error if I cant". It is the only method that makes sense.

Comment: BTW, `all(p=1)` is saying *"all of the assignment of `1` to `p` is non-false"*, meaning that you are assignment a singular value of `1` to the object `p`. You should likely use `==` instead of `=` (as well as steps hinted by @Oliver's comment).

Comment: So when I define weightOfDies it would possibly be something like weightOfDies <- (1:6, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = p/sum(p)) ? Then roll can be defined within the If Statement with sample.